# How can I handle a multi-layered stacking context issue without using 3d transforms or perspective?

Tags: html, css

Is there a way to implement [this](https://jsfiddle.net/nf75b4cj/) without using *3D transforms / perspective*?

```css
* {
  margin: 0;
  box-sizing: border-box;
}

body,
html {
  height: 100vh;
}


/* main = body (in real app) */

main {
  transform-style: preserve-3d;
  height: 100vh;
}

section.container {
  display: contents;
  position: relative;
  height: 100vh;
}

section.container section.list {
  transform-style: preserve-3d;
  display: grid;
  grid-template-rows: auto auto auto;
  grid-row-gap: 10px;
  position: absolute;
  top: 50%;
  left: 50%;
  width: 45vw;
  transform: translate(-50%, -50%);
}

div.item {
  height: 50px;
  background-color: white;
}

div.item.highlighted {
  transform: translateZ(10px);
}

section.modal {
  position: fixed;
  top: 0;
  left: 0;
  width: 100vw;
  height: 100vh;
  background-color: #0009;
  transform: translateZ(5px);
}

section.image {
  position: absolute;
  top: 0;
  left: 0;
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
}

section.image img {
  display: block;
  object-fit: cover;
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
}

span.content {
  background-color: white;
  position: fixed;
  top: calc(50% + 20vw);
  left: 50%;
  transform: translate(-50%, -50%);
}
```

```html
<main>
  <section class="container">
    <section class="image">
      <img src="https://html5up.net/uploads/demos/story/images/banner.jpg">
    </section>
    <section class="list">
      <div class="item">Item 1</div>
      <div class="item">Item 2</div>
      <div class="item highlighted">Item 3</div>
    </section>
  </section>
  <section class="modal">
    <span class="content">modal content</span>
  </section>
</main>
```

I believe the creation rules of *stacking context* do not allow it. The `content` has to be **centered** and one of the best ways to do that is to use `position`, `top/left`, and `transform: translate`. But when you do that, a new *stacking context* is created and all `.item`s are put inside. By that I can apply `z-index` only to all `.item`s over `.modal` and vice versa.

**3D perspective** can solve that, but I wonder if this is the only solution, or if there is another (DOM restructuring and putting `.modal` somewhere else, ...) I tried like everything I can think of, but with no success and I still believe I'm missing something.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can avoid all the transform and center your element differently they you can use `z-index`. Simply avoid setting any `z-index` to container to avoid the stacking context creating. Only use `z-index` with the modal element and the element you want to hightlight.

```css
* {
  margin: 0;
  box-sizing: border-box;
}

body,
html {
  height: 100vh;
}


/* main = body (in real app) */

main {
  height: 100vh;
}

section.container {
  height: 100vh;
  display: flex;
}

section.container section.list {
  display: grid;
  grid-template-rows: auto auto auto;
  grid-row-gap: 10px;
  width: 45vw;
  margin:auto;
  position: relative;
}

div.item {
  height: 50px;
  background-color: white;
}

div.item.highlighted {
  z-index:10;
  position:relative;
}

section.modal {
  position: fixed;
  top: 0;
  left: 0;
  width: 100vw;
  height: 100vh;
  background-color: #0009;
  z-index:5;
}

section.image {
  position: absolute;
  top: 0;
  left: 0;
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
}

section.image img {
  display: block;
  object-fit: cover;
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
}

span.content {
  background-color: white;
  position: fixed;
  top: calc(50% + 20vw);
  left: 50%;
  transform: translate(-50%, -50%);
}
```

```html
<main>
  <section class="container">
    <section class="image">
      <img src="https://html5up.net/uploads/demos/story/images/banner.jpg">
    </section>
    <section class="list">
      <div class="item">Item 1</div>
      <div class="item">Item 2</div>
      <div class="item highlighted">Item 3</div>
    </section>
  </section>
  <section class="modal">
    <span class="content">modal content</span>
  </section>
</main>
```

Comment: Ok, I'm definitelly missing something... Are there two types of context? Because child of flex should create a another context by https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/CSS_Positioning/Understanding_z_index/The_stacking_context but It seems it doesn't. I really don't understand why this solution (over flexbox) works and why using transformation or isolation does not. Could you please explain it? Whats difference (in context creation) between transform and child of flexbox?

Comment: @vbargl simply read it again and you will notice this `z-index value other than auto.` .. so if there is no z-index specified there is no stacking contexnt ;)

Comment: Oh... Such a stupid mistake! Thanks, I totally miss that... So in this case, the element with z-index will create new context but also will show exactly as I need?

Comment: @vbargl yes exactly ;)